# How to add in 'Model Data' &'External ID' in Duplicated view form for Odoo

Tags: odoo

I have duplicated a QWeb form page from >Settings>>Technical>>User Interface>>Views. However, what I found was that the following fields are missing:

- Model Data
- External ID

How am I able to add in the following details, such that within the website, I could reference a menu title to the following view? Because at this point in time, I am not able to reference the duplicated view.

Hence, when I display the following views in listview, the duplicated view will be missing; the external Id, all are classified as QWeb in View type. I am not able to paste the pic, rep still too low

Please help.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create your custom module and add xml file in which you can add your view.

```
<record id="view_hr_attendance_list_report_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">hr.hr.attendance.list.report.tree</field>
            <field name="model">hr.attendance.list.report</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="Attendance List" create="false">
                    <field name="employee_id" />
                    <field name="offline_hours" sum="Offline Hours" widget="float_time"/>
                    <field name="external_hours" sum="External Hours" widget="float_time"/>
                    <field name="shop_hours" sum="Shop Hours" widget="float_time"/>
                    <field name="total_hours" sum="Total Hours" widget="float_time"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Add this xml file into the **openerp**.py file. 
Install this module and you will get external id.
Hope this helps.

Comment: am I able to add the external Id from the setting module itself rather than editing in the python code

Comment: Export that view record it will generate external id for that record if not there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **create a new identifier** for the view.
Go to Settings > Technical > Sequences & Identifiers > External Identifiers and create a new external id.

Note that the Record ID is the id you see in the browser’s address bar when you open, in debug mode, the view just duplicated (like 603 in “…/web#id=**603**&view_type=…”)

Answer (score 0):

Records you enter via the UI will not have an XML ID until you export them.

Exporting them will set the XML-ID, all you need to export is the NAME and ID field so that you can check its correctness.

Once you have exported it, data created by UI will have XML_ID.
[Groups which have been manually created, now have their XML_ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tuDV.png)

I actually found the answer on [odoo forum](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-find-technical-name-xml-id-of-a-user-group-7318), adding it here in case anyone is searching for it.